# Find position of number

Tags: python, random

I need to find the position of a number which is randomly chosen within certain ranges.
EX: `(start, stop, step): (3,6,1)` 
This corresponds to `(3,4,5,6)`
Out of this one number is chosen randomly and I want to find a way to get the position of the number after enumerating it without using lists.

The code looks like the following:

```
tuple_val = (3,6,1) #or any value
rand_val = randint(tuple_val[0], tuple_val[1]) 
for val in range(tuple_val[0], tuple_val[1], tuple_val[2]):
    if rand_val == val:
        #FIND INDEX OF rand_val
```

how would I go about finding the index of this random number?

Comment: In your example `rand_val = randint(tuple_val[0], tuple_val[1]) ` could return non existent integer due to step;

Comment: Assuming it takes only existing values. This is just to find out how to find the index dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your are running on a `range` you have much simpler way of finding out your index - without going over a loop at all.

`index = (rand_val  - tuple_val[0]) /  tuple_val[2]`
`index = (rand_val - start) / * step`

for example if you want to index of the number 4 in your example it is just:
`(4-3) / 1 = 1`

based on your comment that the number must exist .

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
tuple_val = (3,6,1) #or any value
rand_val = randint(tuple_val[0], tuple_val[1]) 
for idx, val in enumerate(range(tuple_val[0], tuple_val[1], tuple_val[2])):
    if rand_val == val:
        #idx is your index
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to iterate, since ranges can be mathematically described (Python 3):

```
def find_in_range(value, r):
    if value not in r:
        return False
    return (value - r.start) // r.step

tuple_val = (3, 6, 1)
print(find_in_range(5, range(*tuple_val)))
# => 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider your

```
tuple_val = (3,6,1) #or any value
rand_val = randint(tuple_val[0], tuple_val[1])
```

Then

```
rand_val - tuple_val[0]
```

denotes the difference to the starting point of the interval and

```
index = (rand_val - tuple_val[0]) / tuple_val[2]
```

gives you the number of steps which is the same as the index you are looking for.